# React js show time left from a set date to now

Tags: reactjs, datetime, components

I've made a class component to show and render current time from new Date() function. What I wanted is to show the amount of time left by subtracting the now Date() to a time in the future. Say now is 1 p.m and the future time is 3 p.m, it will show 2:00:00.

This is my current code for current time.

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { date: new Date() };
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
        () => this.tick(),
        1000
    );
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
}
tick() {
    this.setState({
        date: new Date()
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Waktu tersisa {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show *how* you want to use this future date? It doesn't seem to be in your code.

Comment: use a time library like Moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiate a fixed date-time of your choice. Calculate the difference (in milliseconds) between that fixed time and current time on each **tick**. Convert milliseconds to hours, minutes, and seconds before displaying.

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let fixDate = (new Date()).setHours(15,0,0); // for 3:00:00 pm
        let currDate = new Date();
        this.state = { fixDate, diff: fixDate-currDate };
    }

    ....

    tick() {
        this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
            diff: prevState.fixDate - (new Date()).getTime(),
        }));
    }

    ....

    render() {
        const { diff } = this.state;
        const hours = Math.floor(diff/(60*60*1000));
        const mins = Math.floor((diff-(hours*60*60*1000))/(60*1000));
        const secs = Math.floor((diff-(hours*60*60*1000)-(mins*60*1000))/1000);

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Waktu tersisa {hours}:{mins}:{secs}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `Moment.js` :

```
const currentDate = moment();
const future = moment('2019-03-02 10:03:02');
const timeLeft = moment(future.diff(currentDate)).format("HH:mm:ss");
```

See [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for further explanation.